# Give an example of using subsonic 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, subsonic3

Give me please an example on how to use subsonic 3 for: insert, select, update, delete, stored procedure usage.

I am a new user of subsonic and dont know how to use it. Please explain it to me because I can not find the documentation about this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what do I need to work with subsonic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138499/what-do-i-need-to-work-with-subsonic)

Comment: There are a lot of people who have successfully used SubSonic with the existing documentation. The website has examples and screencasts. Just because you are having problems does NOT mean you should post 3 of the exact same question on StackOverflow at once. That only demonstrates your negative attitude, and no one will want to help you. That said, how to use SubSonic depends on whether you want to use ActiveRecord or Linq. You would start by adding the T4 templates to your project, which will generate classes from your existing DB. From there, selects with Linq are very easy.

Answer (score 2):

Subsonic has great documentation including screencasts.

Have a look: http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Main_Page

Comment: Please give me an example because from the documentation there I cant understant anything

Comment: @Ovidiu: What can't you understand?