# what do I need to work with subsonic?

Tags: c#, subsonic, subsonic3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Give an example of using subsonic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138243/give-an-example-of-using-subsonic-3)

Please tell me what do I need to know to work with subsonic?

What do I need to read and where ? I ask this because I see no documentation on subsonicproject.com.

Please give me a list of to do's that I have to read, understand and be able to work with for the usage of subsonic and usage of ActiveRecord.

Comment: Posting a bad question twice is not going to get you better answers.

Answer (score 2):

How can't you see the documentation? It's right there

http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Main_Page

Comment: Yes I saw that but how does that tell me a beginer how to work with subsonic ? There is no information about how to use subsonic.

Comment: The informations are all there, from setting it up into a project, to its usage.. What do you need?